# "The operation overflows" in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I found something interesting about C#'s primitive data type;
The range of C#'s `long` integer type is -2^63 ~ 2^63-1;
`long.MaxValue = 9223372036854775807`
And `int` type's range is -2^31 ~ 2^31-1.
`int.MaxValue = 2147483647`
So now here's the problem.
Here is the program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"long.Max: {long.MaxValue}");
    Console.WriteLine($"int.Max: {int.MaxValue}");
    int f = int.MaxValue;
    long x = f + 1;
    Console.WriteLine($"int.Max + 1: {x}");
}
```

And I run this code by command `dotnet run`.
And I got this:

```
long.Max: 9223372036854775807
int.Max: 2147483647
int.Max + 1: -2147483648
```

So, why the value of `x` is `-2147483648` not `2147483648`?

Comment: Because you get an Integer overflow. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow. You need first to cast one of the summands to a larger data type.

Comment: You can replace `1` with `1L`. This will force the addition to use `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: The variable `f` is an `int`. So is the literal `1`. Add two ints and you get an int. Assign that int to a long, and it converts the value to long (after the overflow). Try changing your code to `long x = f + 1L;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is running into ‘int’ overflow because the expression is ‘int + int’. Promote one of the operands first to make it ‘long + long’. The usage of the result is not taken into consideration at this point.

Compare with the following alternatives which would produce the expected output.

```
long x = f + 1L;      // int + long -> long + long

long x = (long)f + 1; // long + int -> long + long

long f_l = f;
long x = f_l + 1;
```